# How to make a ListView public in .NET winforms?

Tags: c#, listview, access-modifiers

How can I make a ListView public so I can access it from my first form?

Comment: public ListView theList;

Comment: You are going to have to add a some more detail before anyone knows what you are actually asking. As it stands this question is unanswerable.

Comment: I disagree, I found the question quite answerable, albeit unreadable :). No flaming intended of course.

Comment: It is answerable now the question has been updated to include a reference to WinForms. Until that point the question could easily have been about a WebForms ListView or just about anything else called ListView.

Comment: In fact we still don't know if the questioner is asking about WinForms ListView, as it wasn't him that added WinForms to the question title...

Answer (score 4):

By default when you drop a control on to a form the access modifier is private. You can simply go to the property screen of that control and scroll to Modifiers and set it to public or internal.

I personally dont encourage for you to expose the control from one form to the other. You should be able to easily achieve what you need to do through registering and raising events and let the form that owns the listview to handle it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to create a public readonly property to the ListView, e.g.:

```
public ListView MyListView {
    get {
        return myPrivateListView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why would you want to expose the listview? Isn't it the data of the listview you are after?

You can do this with a [getter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287786(VS.71).aspx) method